# How to know whether a full string is partially matched with patterns?

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I want to search elements in a xml that sub string of file is not matched with any pattern and then remove the element from the root.

1. I want to know there is other approach to search whether the sub string of full  path is matched with one of patterns or not.
2. I want to know how to remove the match item from the root.

Could you let me get some advice.

Here is my sample script

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = ElementTree()
    root.parse('errors.xml')
    patterns = ['/cm-audio/src/main/', '/reprogram-manager/']
    for error in errors:
        file = error.find('file').text
        bMatch = False
        for p in patterns :
            if p in file :
                bMattch = True
                break
        if bMatch == False :
            root.remove(error) #it doesn't work.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import re
    pylines='<date><Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">dd<SignedDataencoding="base64"><Data>cc</Data><date>'
    way1='<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">(.*?)<SignedDataencoding="base64"><Data>(.*?)</Data>'
    partens = re.compile(way1,re.S)
    items1 = re.findall(partens,pylines)
    print items1
```

Hi you can use the re model in python for example like these,
if you want to remove ,you can save other xml skip if math the conditions

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, you have a naming error.

```
bMattch = True
```

should be

```
bMatch = True
```

Without that, `bMatch` can never be `True`.